How to darken a background image in SwiftUI but exclude the area inside a transparent mockup?


I have a SwiftUI view where I display a background image with a mockup of an iPhone over it. The mockup has a transparent area to show the background image. I want to add a Color.black.opacity(0.2) overlay to darken the background image for better readability of the content. However, I want the dark overlay to exclude the transparent area of the mockup.
I tried the following approach:
Color.black.opacity(0.2)
    .ignoresSafeArea()
    .overlay(
        Image(.mockup)
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .blendMode(.destinationOut)
)


This approach doesn’t seem to work as expected—the dark overlay is still visible over the mockup’s transparent area.
Here’s the full code for context:
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var name: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image(.cover)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            
            VStack {
                Image(.mockup)
                
                Spacer()
                
                Text("Lucas & Lavínia")
                    .font(.title)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                
                Spacer().frame(height: 24)
                
                TextField(
                    "",
                    text: $name,
                    prompt: Text("Nome").foreground(.white)
                )
                .padding(15)
                .background(.white.opacity(0))
                .overlay(
                    RoundedRectangle(
                        cornerRadius: 8
                    )
                    .stroke(
                        .white,
                        lineWidth: 1
                    )
                )
                .clipShape(.rect(cornerRadius: 8))
                .foregroundStyle(.white)
                
                Spacer().frame(height: 24)
                
                Button {
                    
                } label: {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Selecionar fotos da galeria")
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding(.vertical, 15)
                    .background(.red)
                    .cornerRadius(40)
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                
                Spacer().frame(height: 24)
                
                Button {
                    
                } label: {
                    Text("Capturar foto agora")
                }
                
                Spacer().frame(height: 35)
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .foregroundStyle(.white)
            .padding(.all)
            .padding(.top, 25)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

How can I apply the black overlay only to the parts of the background image that are not covered by the mockup? Is there a way to mask or exclude the area inside the transparent section of the mockup? Or would I need a completely different approach to achieve this effect?
Any guidance or code examples would be greatly appreciated!

Instead of an overlay, how about just do .brightness(-0.5)? It doesn’t do exactly the same thing, but I think for your purposes it doesn’t matter.

But it will still change the whole image, I wanted it to be just the part around the mockup

Can you show the expected result as a screenshot? Your added image just confused me even more. Show separately what the .cover and .mockup images are.

Done! Added mockup image and cover image

First of all, I would suggest showing the base image in the background of the ZStack, instead of as the first layer of the ZStack. This way, the overflow from scaling-to-fill will not cause the ZStack to extend off-screen.
Then, a masking layer can be added as the first layer of the ZStack, which is seen above the background image.

The mask is formed using semi-transparent Color.black.

A RoundedRectangle is overlayed over the semi-transparent background. The corner radius should approximately match the shape of the mockup.

The rounded rectangle is applied using .blendMode(.destinationOut). This causes the shape to be cut out from the underlying semi-transparent black layer.

The modifier .compositingGroup() is applied, to prevent blend mode from burning deeper into lower layers.


To match the size and position of the cut-out with the mockup image in the VStack, .matchedGeometryEffect can be used. This requires a namespace:
@Namespace private var ns

Here is the example with updates applied:
ZStack {
    Color.black
        .opacity(0.5)
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .overlay {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 40)
                .inset(by: 4)
                .fill(.black)
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "mockup", in: ns, isSource: false)
                .blendMode(.destinationOut)
        }
        .compositingGroup()

    VStack {
        Image(.mockup)
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "mockup", in: ns)

        // ... other content as before
    }
    // ... modifiers as before
}
.background {
    Image(.cover)
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFill()
        .ignoresSafeArea()
}



Benzy, I have already answered it below using blend mode and composition. :)

@AbdulKarimKhan I don't think you addressed the issue of positioning. Your square-cornered rectangle is just somewhere in the middle. If the downvote was from you then I'm disappointed.

It works!! Thank you!

I have removed it, nvm. Happy coding! We are here to assist each other and contribute. I am glad it worked for Lucas.

@AbdulKarimKhan Thank you. The downvote on yours was not from me so I can't do anything about that, sorry.

The downvote isnt mine too... sorry about you @AbdulKarimKhan.
